# OpenAI GPT-3 API: What is the difference between davinci and text-davinci-003?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I'm testing the different models for OpenAI, and I noticed that not all of them are developed or trained enough to give a reliable response.

The models I tested are the following:

```
model_engine = "text-davinci-003"
model_engine = "davinci" 
model_engine = "curie" 
model_engine = "babbage" 
model_engine = "ada"
```

I need to understand what the difference is between `davinci` and `text-davinci-003`, and how to improve the responses to match that response when you use ChatGPT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR

- `text-davinci-003` is the newer and more capable model than `davinci`
- `text-davinci-003` supports a longer context window than `davinci`
- `text-davinci-003` was trained on a more recent dataset than `davinci`
- `text-davinci-003` is cheaper than `davinci`
- `text-davinci-003` is not available for fine-tuning, while `davinci` is

#### Capabilities

As stated in the official [OpenAI article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6643408-how-do-davinci-and-text-davinci-003-differ):

> While both `davinci` and `text-davinci-003` are powerful [models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models), they
> differ in a few key ways.
>
> `text-davinci-003` is the newer and more capable model, designed
> specifically for [instruction-following](https://openai.com/research/instruction-following) tasks. This enables it to
> respond concisely and more accurately - even in zero-shot scenarios,
> i.e. without the need for any examples given in the prompt. `davinci`,
> on the other hand, can be fine-tuned on a specific task, which can
> make it very effective if you have access to at least a few hundred
> training examples.
>
> Additionally, `text-davinci-003` supports a longer context window (max
> prompt+completion length) than davinci - 4097 tokens compared to
> `davinci`'s 2049.
>
> Finally, `text-davinci-003` was trained on a more recent dataset,
> containing data up to June 2021. These updates, along with its support
> for [Inserting text](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/completion/inserting-text), make `text-davinci-003` a particularly versatile and
> powerful model we recommend for most use-cases.

Use `text-davinci-003` because the other models you mentioned in your question are less capable.

If you buy a ChatGPT Plus subscription, you can also use `gpt-3.5-turbo` or `gpt-4`. So, to get similar responses as you get from ChatGPT, it depends on whether you are subscribed or not. For sure, `gpt-3.5-turbo` and `gpt-4` are even more capable than `text-davinci-003`.

#### Costs

`text-davinci-003` is cheaper than `davinci`, as stated on the official [OpenAI website](https://openai.com/pricing):

| MODEL | USAGE |
| --- | --- |
| davinci | $0.1200 / 1K tokens |
| text-davinci-003 | $0.0200 / 1K tokens |

#### Fine-tuning availability

`text-davinci-003` is not available for fine-tuning, while `davinci` is, as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/what-models-can-be-fine-tuned):

> Fine-tuning is currently only available for the following base models:
> `davinci`, `curie`, `babbage`, and `ada`. These are the original models that
> do not have any instruction following training (like `text-davinci-003`
> does for example).

| MODEL | FINE-TUNING AVAILABILITY | TRAINING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| davinci | Yes | $0.0300 / 1K tokens |
| text-davinci-003 | No |  |

Answer (score 6):

I'll complement [Rok Benko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10347145/rok-benko)'s  answer with this great visual summary by [Yao Fu <yao.fu@ed.ac.uk>](https://yaofu.notion.site/How-does-GPT-Obtain-its-Ability-Tracing-Emergent-Abilities-of-Language-Models-to-their-Sources-b9a57ac0fcf74f30a1ab9e3e36fa1dc1):

[image]